# Reading txt file with more than one space as a delimiter in Python

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a text file in which **columns are separated by more than one space**. The problem is that values in each column can also by separated, but at most with **only one space**. So it may look like this

```
aaaxx   123 A   xyz   456 BB 
zcbb  a b   XYZ   xtz 1 
cdddtr  a  111  tddw
```

Is there any way to read such a table? I've tried a few approaches and I think I have to use some kind of regular expression for a delimiter, but honestly I have no idea how to resolve this.

Comment: `re.split('  +', 'aaaxx   123 A   xyz   456 BB ')`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Other solution, using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.txt", sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python", header=None)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        0      1    2       3
0   aaaxx  123 A  xyz  456 BB
1    zcbb    a b  XYZ   xtz 1
2  cdddtr      a  111    tddw
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use a regexp

```py
import re

content = """aaaxx   123 A   xyz   456 BB 
zcbb  a b   XYZ   xtz 1 
cdddtr  a  111  tddw
"""

# Split the content on new lines
rows = content.split("\n")

# Create a 2D list (table) out of the values
table = []

for row in rows:
    row_arr = []
    # The "[ ]" is the regexp equivalent of "space" and {2,} means 2+
    for column in re.split("[ ]{2,}", row):
    # If the row is empty, don't add it to the table
    if len(row_arr):
        table.append(row_arr)

print(table)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are two implementations that I would use. They are based on parity: the split by two spaces keeps the values separated by a single space together, the values separated by an even number of spaces are correctly split, and the uneven cases are cleaned with the `strip` method. The remaning empty strings are filtered out.

```py
content = """aaaxx   123 A   xyz   456 BB 
zcbb  a b   XYZ   xtz 1 
cdddtr  a  111  tddw"""


def split_file_content(file_content: str) -> list[list[str]]:
    """If you don't like regex"""
    return [
        [part.strip() for part in row.split("  ") if part]
        for row in file_content.split("\n")
    ]


def split_file_content_loops(file_content: str) -> list[list[str]]:
    """If you don't like regex AND list comprehensions"""
    table = []
    for row in file_content.split("\n"):
        values = []
        for part in row.split("  "):
            if part:
                values.append(part.strip())
        table.append(values)
    return table


print(split_file_content(content))
print(split_file_content_loops(content))
```